Was ist die beste Übersetzung von "to listen out for"?
Zum Beispiel, "the kids listen out for Santa Claus on Christmas night", oder, "I listen out for my favorite song on the radio."
Ich habe "auf X horchen" und "auf X lauschen" als Empfehlungen gesehen, aber was ist richtig?
Danke im Voraus!

My understanding of the english phrase is that you listen out for a potential sound that may or may not come, or for a sound you expect in the future. Both "lauschen" and "horchen" do not convey that of themselves, they can both be used in situations where the sound is there, but hearing it depends on your attention.
To say that the sound is maybe not there (yet), in German you have to spell that out, normally in a subclause.
Webster has two example sentences for the phrase. Here is how I would translate them:

We listened out for (the sound of) his footsteps.
Wir lauschten, ob wir (den Klang seiner) Schritte hören konnten.


We saw lightning and listened out for the thunder.
Wir sahen Blitze und warteten auf den Donner.

In the second example, the verb only describes the "waiting for", but leaves out that it is done by listening. Your christmas example can work in a comparable way, using "hören" only in the explanatory subclause:

Die Kinder warten in der Christnacht darauf, ob sie den Weihnachtsmann hören können.

If you leave out the conditional "ob", that implies the sound will come, as in the English "until Santa Claus comes".

Die Kinder warten in der Christnacht darauf, den Weihnachtsmann zu hören.

Another variant would use a figurative expression to highlight the point in time when the plot thickens:

Die Kinder spitzen die Ohren, ob sie den Weihnachtsmann hören können.

"Die Ohren spitzen" is derived from the way some animals right up their ears for better listening and conveys intense concentration. It is the German phrase that comes closest to the "potentiality" aspect of listen out for, but the action described can only be kept up for a short period of time.

It's lauschen+‹Dat›. Not lauschen auf, that doesn't exist.

Ich lausche meinem Lieblingslied im Radio.

You can't simply translate the sentence with Santa Claus into German because he doesn't come through the smokestack during Christmas night in Germany. German kids get their presents on Christmas Eve out of Santa's hands.
If you wanted to do it nevertheless, it would be

Die Kinder lauschen, ob der Weihnachtsmann kommt.

The verb horchen is better suited for eavesdropping.

Sie horcht an der Tür.


But ich lausche meinem Lieblingslied doesn't mean I'm waiting for the song. It's already playing. Isn't it?

Oh, I misunderstood the meaning of the English phrase then.
